# Automatically Clicking Button on a Specific Webpage

Tags: greasemonkey, userscripts

I am currently taking an online course offered by my school. Every time I log in I am taking to a terms of use agreement, and must accept it every single time I log into it.

Is there any way using something like a Greasemonkey script, automatically push the accept button when this appears. Generally is there such a way to press a button when a specific page/link is navigated to?

Comment: It's not 100% automatic, but you could try iMacros?

Comment: The question doesn't show any research effort. Please checkout [ask].

Comment: @Rubén Okay, the question is answered, can you please just stop.

Comment: @ComputerLocus: I was checking questions without accepted answers.  By the way, thanks for coming back and accept an answer.

Comment: @ComputerLocus: besides that you find my comments annoying, I'm sorry about that, every time that you post a comment to this question, an accepted entry is made on your activity log. That confused me, I'm sorry for that too.

Comment: @Rubén I unaccepted and reaccepted the question when I saw your original comment just to make sure I had accepted it because I couldn't see any other reason someone would be digging in the graveyard of questions nitpicking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would write a simple jquery script and add includes to jquery from the CDN.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
     setTimeout(function() {
           $("a.NAMEOFTHEBUTTON").trigger('click');
        },10);
       });
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, I will give this a try. I never have actually made a Userscript with Chrome before, but I would be able to use this piece of code in one? Correct?

Comment: One problem I realized, is that this is not checking the actual URL of the site. This means that any button with the same label as the one of the site I'm talking about, would also be autoclicked, which is not good.

Comment: you'll have to add `@include  http://www.example.com/*` to run it on specific site, replacing example.com with your site. For Chrome extensions, it has to be the match pattern http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html